# jquery click event reference with [this]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some hyperlinks and when user clicks on any of them I want to direct the user to that particular link. I am accessing the href attribute with jquery. Below is the code.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="class-name">link1</a>            
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="class-name">link1</a>          
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="class-name">link1</a>
```

Now I want to access the URL with jQuery I am using the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.class-name').click(function(){
    var linkHref=$("this.class-name").attr('href');
    alert(linkHref);
    $('.redirect').attr('href',linkHref);       
});
```

But I am getting "undefined" in the alert.

All your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no element `this` with class `redirectLink` in your code. In fact, no element has class `redirectLink`.

Comment: please see the edited version. sorry for the confusion. I copied from the wrong loc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var linkHref=$(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: then you probably have typo somewhere, sometimes stupid things happen, like messing Cyrillic a,e,o with Latin a,e,o, or your script is cached and you make changes but the browser uses the old one

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.class-name').click(function(){
        var linkHref=$(this).attr('href');
        alert(linkHref);     
});
```

this is the object < a > that you selected with the click method. Thus you do not need to let jQuery search for the object based on class or id as previously. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

`this` is a special identifier that gets the context that your function is called in.  It doesn't make sense to write `"this"`; the `jQuery` function has no way of knowing what your `this` is.

You probably want `$(this)`.

You can also write `$(this).find('.redirectLink')`, but that isn't the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this refers to the current object in scope. In the case of a click event this refers to the hyperlink being clicked. But do not enclose it in quotes.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.class-name').click(function(){
     var linkHref=$(this).attr('href');
     alert(linkHref);
     $('.redirect').attr('href',linkHref);       
   });
 });
```

you could shorten this to:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.class-name').click(function(){
     $('.redirect').attr('href',$(this).attr('href'));       
   });
 });
```